# Evaluate and log multiple variables at breakpoint in CLion?

Tags: clion

In CLion, is it possible to "Evaluate and Log" multiple variables or make a string expression at a breakpoint? Simple syntax that I try (e.g. printf) doesn't work.

For example, if I wanted to display the value of variables "a" and "b" in the console at a breakpoint, what do I put in the "Evaluate and Log" text box on the Breakpoints dialog?  Note that "a" and "b" may be different types.

Thanks! -- Adam

Comment: I should add that I'm using `gdb` as the underlying debugger

Comment: I believe, you should use the underlying debugger (gdb) [expression syntax](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_51.html) for it. [Pretty-printer](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty-Printing.html) in `~/.gdbrc` may also help.